# How to sort this array by section of 5 numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Please guys, some one help me to sort this array?

I want to sort between five first numbers. like:
`n[0], n[1], n[2],n[3],n[4]` - sort this values, then...
sort more 5, and more 5, and more 5, until finish.
i don't wanna to short all this array. I want to short by 5 to 5.
if my array complete first 5 numbers like: 30 12 13 42 55, i want to shot this values and the next 5 number should be sorted again.
Have some way to do that?

```
public class randomNumbers{

    int n[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,     // 0 to 4
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 5 to 9
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 10 to 14
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 15 to 19
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 20 to 24
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 25 to 29
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 30 to 34
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 35 to 39
            0,0,0,0,0,     // 40 to 44
            0,0,0,0,0 };   // 45 to 49



    int s[] = {   0,0,       // 0 to 1
            0,0,       // 2 to 3
            0,0,       // 4 to 5
            0,0,       // 6 to 7
            0,0,       // 8 to 9
            0,0,       // 10 to 11
            0,0,       // 12 to 13
            0,0,       // 14 to 15
            0,0,       // 16 to 17
            0,0, };    // 18 to 19
    HashSet<Integer> used = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public randomNumbers(){

        Random rand = new Random();

        int i;
        int g;

        for (g = 0; g != n.length; g++) {

            int add = 1+ (int)(Math.random() * 50);

            while (used.contains(add)) { number
                add = 1+ rand.nextInt(50); 

            }
            used.add(add);
             n[g] = add;
            //by this time, add will be unique

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `do { add = ... } while (!used.add(add));` is a better way to add a unique value to a set.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation says:

> java.util
>
> **Class Arrays**
>
> `public static void sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)`
>
> Sorts the specified range of the specified array of objects into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

Then looping like in

```
for (int i=0; i<n.length; i+=5) {
    int end = Math.min(i+5,n.length);
    Arrays.sort(n,i,end);
}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: OP wants to sort `n`, not `s` I think.